# How to set a fixed size for a Tide Sdk app window?

Tags: javascript, window, scale, fixed, tidesdk

I am trying to compile an app, that would have a fixed window size, one that could not be scaled. I found these functions in the API, but they don't seem to work when compiling -

```
var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
window.setHeight(500); // Set the window height to 800 pixels.
window.height = 500; // The same.
window.setMaxHeight(500);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this by just editing the tiapp.xml with maxs and mins closing the width and height. You can also define that the app doesn't maximize or resize:

```
<width>700</width>
<max-width>700</max-width>
<min-width>700</min-width>

<height>500</height>
<max-height>500</max-height>
<min-height>500</min-height>

<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<resizable>false</resizable>
<maximizable>false</maximizable>
<minimizable>true</minimizable>
```

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started: